# ¿Por que la cadena no devuelve la cantidad correcta de letras?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int longitud;
char cad[20];
int i, j;
int acum;

printf("Ingrese la cadena: ");
scanf("%s", cad);
longitud = strlen(cad);

for(i=0;i<longitud;i++){
    if(cad[i]>='a' && cad[i]<='z'){
        acum=acum+j;
        j++;
    }       

}

printf("Hay %d letras\n",acum);
return 0;
}
```

Hola quisiera saber a que se debe de que el programa no me pueda devolver la cantidad de letras correcta a la hora de ejecutarlo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada estas usando las variables **acum** y **j** sin inicializar, esa ya es un problema, hay que inicializar las variables a utilizar para que no se usen con valores basura.

La variable **j** no es necesario, basta con usar la variable **acum** la cual tendrás que incrementar si es una letra, así:

```
acum = 0;
for(i = 0;i < longitud; i++)
{
    if(cad[i] >= 'a' && cad[i] <= 'z')
    {
        acum++;
    }
}
```

Ahora con esto contarías en solo en minúsculas, si tambien querés que detecte las mayúsculas sería:

```
acum = 0;
for(i = 0;i < longitud; i++)
{
    if((cad[i] >= 'a' && cad[i] <= 'z') || (cad[i] >= 'A' && cad[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
        acum++;
    }
}
```